# I am unable to change text color in iOS 14 for UIDatePicker having UIDatePickerStyle.inline

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, ios14

Hi I am trying to change the textcolor for the UIDatePicker if `preferredDatePickerStyle` is `UIDatePickerStyle.inline` its not working, for `UIDatePickerStyle.wheels` and `UIDatePickerStyle.compact` its working

```
timePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
timePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.inline
```

Comment: Your code was always wrong, since you are effectively trying to configure the picker using KVC. That's not supported. This `"textColor"` is some secret key; there was never any guarantee that it would work.

Comment: I understand that it is not safe, but how can I change the font color, for datepicker using style `UIDatePickerStyle.inline`.

Comment: If you think Apple hasn't provided sufficient ability for you to customize this object the way you want to, file an enhancement request with Apple.